# Does Dynamic Azure Service App support slots for swapping

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an issue on what Service Plan to choose for some Azure Functions I want to build. 
I tried to use the Dynamic plan on West Europe but looking into the portal it doesn't support slots. So although a Dynamic Plan would be great for scaling out I am concerned that when we want to do swaps between production - staging - dev we can't do this using a Dynamic plan.
On the other hand looking at classic service plans I can get a S1-2-3 which supports slots. The issue here is that I may be deploying 10 Functions on one Service app, and they may require memory and processing power to operate. What would happen if all these service will execute in the same VM, how they are going to scale? Will VM scale or the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slots are not currently supported in Azure Functions for either Dynamic or Classic service plans. The feature has not been completely disabled yet, but you should expect that certain things will not work correctly if you create a slot and try to do a swap.

To answer your other question, choosing a classic app service plan means you will need to either manage scaling yourself or look into configuring Auto Scale.  More information on scaling with classic app service plans can be found in the official Azure App Service documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/

Comment: Ok so how can I implement a staging like environment with functions? For the moment my functions are HTTP triggers so I was thinking of creating a stub function (say RouteIt) which returns redirects (307) to the proper one. And when the main function is under maintenance just change the redirect urls.